# React/Redux: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

Here is the code of my Component `UserHandler`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import * as actionCreators from '../../store/actions/actions';

class UserHandler extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onInitUsers } = this.props;
    onInitUsers();
  }

  render() {
    // some code
    return (          
        {/* SOME JSX */}
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  //    state to props mapping
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onUserEdition: username => dispatch(actionCreators.editUser(username)),
  onUserSelection: username => dispatch(actionCreators.fetchSelectedUser(username)),
  onInitUsers: () => dispatch(actionCreators.initUsers()),
});

// PropTypes definition and defaultProps

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserHandler);
```

And in my `actionCreators` file, here's what I defined:

```
const initUsersStart = createAction(INIT_USERS_START);
const setUsers = createAction(SET_USERS, users => ({ users }));
const initUsersError = createAction(INIT_USERS_ERROR, error => ({ error }));


const initUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(initUsersStart());
  return axios.get('/users')
    .then(
      response => dispatch(setUsers(response.data)),
    )
    .catch(
      error => dispatch(initUsersError(error)),
    );
};
```

When I comment the `onInitUsers();` call in the `componentDidMount()` function, I no more have the error. I want to understand why this is raising this error.

Finally, here's how my I create my `store`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import reducer from './store/reducers/reducers';

const store = createStore(
  reducer, /* preloadedState, */
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  /* eslint-disable no-undef */ /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  /* eslint-enable */
);

// const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  /* eslint-disable no-undef */
  document.getElementById('root'),
  /* eslint-enable */
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Please note that I have done some research before to find out what may be the root cause of such an error, and it seems that it could emanate from several causes. I checked the ones I found, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you share the code of the `createAction` function?

Comment: The `createAction` function is from https://github.com/pauldijou/redux-act

Comment: what happens if you do onInitUsers: actionCreators.initUsers ?

Comment: @TomaszRozmus: the error disappears, but how to trigger the action creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was posted over in [the React-Redux issues list](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1007), and I answered it there.  I'll paste my solution here for completeness.

First, the root issue is that something that is not a plain action object is reaching the actual store.  You could put a breakpoint in the `dispatch` function in the Redux source code to see what the actual value is (or edit the copy of Redux in your project's `node_modules` folder to add some logging).

Actually, I think I see the problem.  The real issue is that you're passing two separate store enhancers to `createStore`.  One is the middleware enhancer from `applyMiddleware`, the other is the Redux DevTools extension.  You need to "compose" them both together into a combined enhancer.  See the [Configuring Your Store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuringyourstore) page in the Redux docs for a copy-pasteable example of how to do this properly.

Two other suggestions:

Instead of writing a `mapDispatch` function by hand, you can use the "object shorthand", and just pass an object full of action creators directly to `connect`.  You already have an object full of action creators from the `import * as actionCreators` statement, so you can just do: `export default connect(mapState, actionCreators)(UserHandler)`.  (That said, the function names are not the same as the prop names you want, so you might need to make a new object instead like `{onUserSelection : actionCreators.fetchSelectedUser}` and pass that instead.)

Also, we've got a [`redux-starter-kit` package](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-starter-kit) we're working on that has a single function to set up your store for you, and automatically adds both `redux-thunk` and the DevTools Extension.  You might want to try using that instead of setting up the store yourself.

Comment: Thank you @markerikson for your help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Return your axios call thus whichever of the paths your logic follows, an object gets returned as needed by Redux.

```
const initUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(initUsersStart());
  return axios.get('/users')
    .then(
      response => dispatch(setUsers(response.data)),
    )
    .catch(
      error => dispatch(initUsersError(error)),
    );
};
```

After having tested your code I think the problem also lies in your store configuration. Middlewares should be applied as last argument of `createStore` function:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer, /* preloadedState, */
  /* eslint-disable no-undef */ /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  /* eslint-enable */
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
);
```

I tested this with redux v.4.0.0 and react-redux v.5.0.7.

Comment: Done (thank you), but this doesn't solve the problem I encouter.

Comment: Now you got rid of the error, apply the suggestion by @Laurenz Glück but in this way: `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
});`. Then call it in `componentDidMount()` with: `this.props.actions.initUsers();`.

Comment: I did exactly what you've just suggested, and I still get `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your are dispatching an action with calling `onInitUsers()` because it's inside the `dispatch()` function. If you dispatch an action, you need to return an object with key `type` and optional a payload.

What you need is `bindActionCreators` function inside your `mapDispatchToProps` like this:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onUserEdition: username => dispatch(actionCreators.editUser(username)),
  onUserSelection: username => dispatch(actionCreators.fetchSelectedUser(username)),
  onInitUsers: bindActionCreators(actionCreators.initUsers, dispatch),
});
```

Now you have bind the dispatch function to your initUsers function an can use it like us want.

---

Edit: Try to change your `onInitUser` function to the following:

```
const initUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(initUsersStart());
  return dispatch({
            type: 'GET_USER',
            payload: axios.get('/users')
                .then(
                  response => dispatch(setUsers(response.data)),
                )
                .catch(
                  error => dispatch(initUsersError(error)),
                );
        });
};
```

Comment: I did this but it didn't solve the issue at all. I still get the same error.

Comment: Made the changes exactly as you advised, but still facing the same issue

Comment: Mmm okay, thats strange! I honestly never used something like that... Maybe you have a look at redux-logic: https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic 

It's pretty cool, I use it daily and it will make it really easy for you to do what you want. Let me know I you need some more informations...

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz but I'll have to stick for now to `redux-thunk` to deal with async calls in action creators, and hoopefully find a solution to this issue.